# Django Editable Text Field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've been able to easily create a list of editable items and manage them through the Django admin panel. That seems pretty simple and I have a good idea of how models work from other frameworks.

Although, I'm curious to know to know how I can make something as simple as editing a text area on a static site. Basically, I don't need to "add post" or anything of the sort. I just want to be able to edit a text area on a static site.

Any docs or examples?

I've been looking at packages such as django-flatblocks and chunks, these seem to possibly help with what I'd like to do. I'm just new to the Python world so some of this stuff is a little magic to me, especially involving the administration panel.

One thing that I realized is that these libraries (or apps in django?) seem to be super out of date, stemming back to the last commit being from 2012. Are these still commonly used?

Comment: You can take a look to both Forms and [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/). You can render a simple form and start connecting everything from the view.

Comment: is there no way to utilize django admin for this?

Comment: AFAIK you'd have to mess with admin's source code.  Do you have an example of what you want to do?

Comment: Very simply, it's a static site and I'd like a user to be able to log in to the admin panel, and update a piece of text on the site. For example, if there's an about section on the homepage, I'd like the user to be able to update that text at any time.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out a solution in case anyone is interested. I ended up using a Django application called django-generic-flatblocks which seems to provide me with what I need. Although, it's a bit strange as I had to replace all the text on my site with a gblock and then re-enter it all. Seems as if upon first creation of a block, it's empty so you essentially have to provide it with a value.

After that, if you log into the admin panel you're able to pull up the block and edit it. Alternatively, if you're logged into the Admin panel you're able to view your site and an edit tag is provided and you'll go directly to that block in the admin panel.

If anyone knows of anything which essentially allows me to define the text blocks up front in the admin panel then add the tags to the code, please lmk. I'd prefer to load all my content into the admin panel first and then just throw the tag into the code and have it display. That would save a lot of time in terms of having to copy the existing content, store it away, adding the tag, and then having to put it back in.

This seemed to be the only one of the recommended apps that worked for me. I tried to use Chunks because this really is only for title/text but on Django 1.11 it would freak out on me about not having South.db, which isn't even used.

https://github.com/bartTC/django-generic-flatblocks